# Pages-like database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a Pages-like feature for my music festival website. People wil be able to create a 'Poster' about a band and post links and videos on the Poster. How would I create that in MYSQL.
   Would i create a table for each 'Poster' and list the amount of people that have posted/listed? Or would I create a table of Posters.
   How would I do that? I am using MYSQL. So if someone wants to create one, does a table have to be automatically created?

i just want to know where to start.

Cheers,
Noah

Comment: Not exactly following the concept. Is there any other website with similar functionality that you can use as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would have the following tables:

- Bands
- Posters
- Links
- Videos

Then:

- A band would have many posters.
- A poster would have many links.
- A poster would have many videos.

If X have many Y, then the Y table would include a foreign key pointing to the X table.

So a poster might have the following columns:

- poster_id (primary key)
- band_id (foreign key)
- description (or whatever other meta data appears once on the poster page)
- etc

You wouldn't create a new table for every poster. Tables represent the structure of the data, not a piece of data. Use foreign keys to determine which links, videos, etc belong to which poster.

Use JOINS to get related information from other tables.

Note that the MyISAM storage engine doesn't support foreign keys. Make sure you are using InnoDB.